# OpenCV: Making a curve straight

Tags: opencv, image-processing

[image]

How do I make this curve a straight line  of the same length (basically by unbending it )? I guess I need to apply some kind of non-linear transformation. But I am not sure which transformation will work  best here.

Please note that if I try taking its projection on a straight line, I will end up with a shorter line.

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: It's not quite clear wha do you want. You can do this transform by just substitution of difference between line and curve evenly distributed nodes for example, or by scaling radius vectors of these points, etc.

Comment: do you want to do *exactly* what you asked? Or do you want to correct a line that is straight in the real world but appears curve on a photo?

Comment: skeletonize, count pixels = gives line length. then draw the line segment with the length. that's it i guess ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do connection analysis to get every point(pixel) in the curve, and calculate the pixels number. The length of pixels is the length of transformed line, the orientation can be the two vertex connection line's orientation.